# I'm confused how to print string with quote and script code from rails server side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

**requirement, just print the PURE string whatever user inserted**

This was the input that is inside the database.

```
Sample text
var test= 1234;
function a(){ alert("test");}
testestesetset
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="www.naver.com"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And if i pull out, it shows like this.

```
description = appointment[:description].to_s
Rails.logger.debug("*******test******"+description.html_safe)
```

result,

```
*******test******Sample text
var test= 1234;
function a(){ alert("test");}
testestesetset
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="www.naver.com"/>
</body>
</html>
```

ok, i have to send this data as a javascript param,

```
<span class="hotspot" onmouseover="tooltip.showTitle('<%=description%>',&quot;<%=t("appointments.index.explanation")%>&quot;);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">
```

and if i see the parsed code, it shows like this,

parsed code,

```
<td class="title_cell">
<span class="hotspot" onmouseover="tooltip.showTitle('Sample text
var test= 1234;
function a(){ alert(&quot;test&quot;);}
testestesetset
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
&lt;iframe src=&quot;www.naver.com&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;',&quot;Explanation&quot;);" onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">
```

and throws an error like this,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

i googled a little in here, and found `.html_safe` and `gsub` and `simple_format` etc

but i'm really confused, translating it to pure string.

Can i get some advise with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) or it's alias `j` on ruby statements that you need to escape carriage returns, single and double quotes.

Try:

```
<span class="hotspot" 
      onmouseover="tooltip.showTitle('<%= j description %>','<%= j t("appointments.index.explanation") %>');" 
      onmouseout="tooltip.hide();">
```

Comment: it is only printing Sample text
var test= 1234;
function a(){ alert("test");}
testestesetset

Comment: In that case, please see: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize

Comment: @Canna, another option is: [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw)

Comment: Thanks anyway! :) I'll keep following the ref

Comment: @Canna, sorry, were you expecting sample usage of `raw` or `sanitize` from me?  Are they not working?

Comment: @vee One Vote for you, Great work :) But For printing HTML I used html_safe which works for me